# What does $x2$ mean? Is it $x\cdot 2$ or the variable $x2$?

Tags: notation, education

I'm working on a online mathematical learning environment. There is a mathematical editor where students can give their answers using a graphical interface:

[image]

However, we have had the problem in the past, that our online mathematical editor saw $xy$ as the variable $xy$ of length 2, instead of $x\cdot y$. This confused so many students that we now have an option that $xy$ is seen as $x\cdot y$.

However, now the question arises, what does $x2$ mean? We parse it know as the variable of $x2$ of length $2$.

If the solution of question is $2\cdot x$ and the student would give the answer as $x2$, would a teacher mark that as correct? I'm not sure, I guess it is very uncommon, but we do know from our analysis, that input like this is sometimes given in the editor.

My guess is that the student probably meant $x^2$ or maybe even $x+2$ and maybe mistyped the plus operator.

So my question is, what would be the correct way to parse this? Should we parse it as $x\cdot 2$ or as the variable $x2$?

Comment: So... you're the site developer and you want to know what's the most natural way to do it?

Comment: Why not require the input to be $x_2$ or $x^2$ or $2x$, and give “parse error” for $x2$? That will give students a chance to write what they really mean.

Comment: In my opinion, not everything are correct mathematical notation. Just reject it.

Comment: Usually, for programming languages, operators need to be explicit, and `x2` would be a single variable name.

Comment: If your students can't figure out the right syntax and/or this is not your goal to teach them syntax, I would suggest parsing input in all possible ways and determing if there is the right answer among them.

Comment: @VsevolodA.: That would only teach students to write their answer in the most ambiguous way possible.

Comment: @celtschk getting the right answer this way is much harder than you think. Also you don't have to tell them how you parse.

Comment: @user202729 yes, I'm part of the programming team

Comment: @HansLundmark thanks, I think agree with that, we will probably go for the parse error option indeed

Comment: Maybe the program should give hints...